# How to actually query data from Firestore with GeoFirestore?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I'm trying to query documents near a given point in given radius in Firestore with using GeoFirestore for my node.js project. Firstly, I have a document in the database in this format:
[image]

My query code is like this:

```
// Create the GeoFirestoreQuery object
const geoQuery = geoFirestore.query({
    center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitute, longitude),
    radius: 5,
    query: (ref) => ref.where("d.available", "==", true)
});
```

The thing is that, I cannot figure out how to get the document from the query. I tried the code below, but it simply is not called at all.

```
// Fetch the nearest couriers
const onKeyEnteredRegistiration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, document, distance) {
    console.log(key);
});
```

How can I return the document? What I am missing? Is my query and database structure matches? Is there any missing fields or issues? Or should I use another query instead of "key_entered"? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I think problem is with the data structure. Should I use a map called "d" to store all fields? And should I store geopoint or geohash string in field "g"? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, it was about the database structure. I changed my structure as shown below and now it works perfectly.
[image]

Comment: are you able to get the other fields like `name`, `phone` etc in your snapshot once you do the query? i am only able to see the document `id` :S

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am also unable to get anything besides id